# libpng load file from memory buffer

Tags: libpng

I tried looking through the libpng documentation, but didn't find what I was looking for.

I have a PNG file fully in a memory buffer, how can I load this file (apart from the obvious solution of creating a temporary file)?

<sub>Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm calling libpng from Python using ctypes.</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found [this article](http://pulsarengine.com/2009/01/reading-png-images-from-memory/) which describes pretty well how to read a PNG file from memory.

Summarized, you have to create a custom callback function and give it to `libpng` using `png_set_read_fn`. Then in that callback function you read from your memory buffer rather than a file.

Comment: The link is now dead.

Comment: link has been resurrected

Comment: This is a great resource. One thing I discovered is that if your ReadDataFromInputStream function does not actually copy real PNG data to outBytes, it causes png_read_info() to crash the program. I was just returning placeholder bytes during development, and it was crashing. When I returned real bytes, it worked. (This seems a bit scary since it seems to imply that if the .png file is corrupt, libpng can crash instead of returning an error.)

Comment: Or use fmemopen.