# libbpg - how to pass bytes instead of file path

Tags: c++, c, bpg

I want to use **libbpg** library (written in C) in C++ project (https://github.com/mirrorer/libbpg)

I need to pass image bytes as input instead of the absolute path of the image file and I need the output result in the bytes too (instead of ".png > .bpg" I need "bytes > bytes").

E.g. I would like to capture frames from webcam and convert them to bpg bytes and also pass those bytes over network

`main` function of libbpg's `bpgenc.c` takes a string of file path as input parameter

https://github.com/mirrorer/libbpg/blob/master/bpgenc.c#L2909

Any suggestions how to pass bytes instead of file name?

For example If camera returns image bytes in BGR format then how can I convert it to `Image` of libbpg?

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags, and read their description. The `libpg` tag you selected (and I edited away) is for the database PostgrSQL library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, my mistake

Comment: The README says there's a library for *decoding*, but for encoding you have to use a command line program. If it can't work with standard input and output... Hmm. Maybe pipe data to and from it using fifos?